# texture3d generates GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: glsl

Have a strange issue with my glsl shader. It renders nothing (eg black screen) and makes my glDrawElements cast a GL_INVALID_OPERATION. The shader in use is shown bellow. When I comment out the line with *v = texture3D(texVol,pos).r;* and replace it with *v = 0.4;* it outputs what is expected (orange-like color) and no gl errors is generated.

```
uniform sampler2D texBack;
uniform sampler3D texVol;
uniform vec3 texSize;
uniform vec2 winSize;
uniform float iso;

varying vec3 inCoords;

vec4 raytrace(in vec3 entryPoint,in vec3 exitPoint){
    vec3 dir = exitPoint - entryPoint;
    vec3 pos = entryPoint;
    vec4 color = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
    int steps = int(2.0*length(texSize));
    dir = dir * (1.0/steps);
    vec3 n;
    float v,m=0.0,avg=0.0,avg2=0.0;
    for(int i = 0;i<steps || i < 2500;i++){
        v = texture3D(texVol,pos).r;
        m = max(v,m);
        avg += v;
        pos += dir;
    }
    return vec4(avg/steps,m,0,1);
}

void main()
{
    vec2 texCoord = gl_FragCoord.xy/winSize;
    vec3 exitPoint = texture2D(texBack,texCoord).xyz;
    gl_FragColor = raytrace(inCoords,exitPoint);
}
```

I am using an VBO for rendering a color cube as entry and exist point for my rays. They are stored in FBOs and they look ok when I render them directly to the screen. 
I have tried chaning to glBegin/glEnd and draw the cube with quads and then I get the same errors.
I cant find what I am doing wrong and now I need your help. Why is my texture3D generating GL_INVALID_OPERATION?

Note:
I have enabled both 2d and 3d textures.

**Edit:**

- I've just uploaded the whole project to github. browse to for more code https://github.com/r-englund/rGraphicsLibrary
- This is tested on both Intel HD 3000 and Nvidia GT550m

Answer (score 0):

According to OpenGL specification glDrawElements() generates GL_INVALID_OPERATION in the following cases:

1. If a geometry shader is active and mode is incompatible with the input primitive type of the geometry shader in the currently installed program object.
2. If a non-zero buffer object name is bound to an enabled array or the element array and the buffer object's data store is currently mapped.

This means the problem has nothing to do with your fragment shader. If you don't use geometry shaders, you should fix the buffer objects accordingly.

**It looks like your are not providing additional relevant information in your question.**